# Using Probot to create a Github issue on response from express route

Tags: javascript, express, github, github-api, probot

Is it possible to use Probot to create an issue on response from an express route? I've tried the following, but they async function can't access context.github.

```
 const createIssue = async function (issue, context) {
    const owner = issue.owner; const repo = issue.repo; const title = issue.title; const body = issue.body; const assignees = issue.assignees; const labels = issue.labels
    return context.github.issues.create({ owner, repo, title, body, labels, assignees })
  }
  const router = app.route('/robot')
  router.use(require('express').static('public'))
  router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const issue = {
      repo: 'reponame',
      owner: 'ownername',
      title: req.query.title,
      labels: req.query.lab,
      body: req.query.body,
      assignees: req.query.as
    }
    createIssue(issue, context).then(
      res.send('Success')
    ).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for: https://probot.github.io/api/latest/classes/application.html#auth

```js
const createIssue = async function (issue, app) {
    const github = await app.auth();
    const owner = issue.owner; const repo = issue.repo; const title = issue.title; const body = issue.body; const assignees = issue.assignees; const labels = issue.labels
    return github.issues.create({ owner, repo, title, body, labels, assignees })
  }
  const router = app.route('/robot')
  router.use(require('express').static('public'))
  router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    const issue = {
      repo: 'reponame',
      owner: 'ownername',
      title: req.query.title,
      labels: req.query.lab,
      body: req.query.body,
      assignees: req.query.as
    }
    const 
    createIssue(issue, app).then(
      res.send('Success')
    ).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```